# Securing ASP.NET WebAPI - Custom Login + Social Login

Tags: oauth, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0

I am writing an ASP.Net WebApi application and I want to secure it using a combination of Custom Login (like ASP.NET Membership) and Social Logins (Google,Facebook,Twitter,LinkedIn and hopefully many more). User should be able to select any of them.

My client is pure HTML/JS SPA application and for that i will need to implement Implict grant flow of OAuth.

The options i see right now are

1. Use Thinktecture's Identity Server and Authorization Server.
2. Use DotNetOpenAuth library.

Can anyone point me in the right direction ? Which one of the above options can work for me?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not follow the same pattern in MVC 5 SPA template, which already did exactly what you want to do:

1. It uses resource owner password login flow with ASP.NET Identity API
2. Support Social Login (Google, Facebook, Twitter, Microsoft Account)
3. Its client uses knockout and pure html/js
4. It uses implicit grant flow to convert social login to application access token

The template uses OWIN security middlewares, which can support:

1. Cookie auth
2. Bearer token auth
3. Social login auth
4. OAuth 2.0 Authorization Server flows and extension grant, which you can customize your own

You may need [my blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/09/20/understanding-security-features-in-spa-template.aspx) to better understand the whole security story in the SPA template.

Comment: Excellent..Quick question though, Will I be able to add more OpenID providers like say LinkedIn, Yahoo etc. easily ? I haven't gone through entire article. Apologize if this has been addressed in your blog and links in your blog.

Comment: You can implement your own OpenID provider just like what google auth middleware does: http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google/GoogleAuthenticationHandler.cs. However, there is no base class for openid provider. It means you need to implement it from scratch.